# How to open a URL (generated using XMLNode in MS Word) open in a new window?

Tags: ms-word, xmldocument, xmlnode

I am creating a word document report where a website hyperlink will be generated using below code.
Here I am using w:tgtFrame='_blank' but no use that it still gets opened in the same browser.
Please let me know for the solution.

```
<w:document>
                                                <w:p w:rsidR='00CA103F' w:rsidRDefault='00CA103F' w:rsidP='00264350'>
                                                    <w:r>
                                                        <w:t>Website: </w:t>
                                                    </w:r>
                                                    <w:hyperlink r:id='rId100' w:history='1' w:tgtFrame='_blank'>
                                                        <w:r w:rsidRPr='00CA103F'>
                                                            <w:rPr>
                                                                <w:rStyle w:val='Hyperlink' />
                                                                <w:rFonts w:cs='Arial' />
                                                                <w:u w:val='single' />
                                                            </w:rPr>
                                                            <w:t>" + Website + "</w:t>
                                                        </w:r>
                                                    </w:hyperlink>
                                                 </w:p>
                                             </w:document>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this from another forum:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/hyperlinks-in-msword-2010-target-frame-issue/e65c6ee2-6b3c-475f-8d01-1f5b49f91a09

It looks like Adobe issue that the URL will display in the same window and now solution yet from Adobe.